# Heroku - Error H10 (App crashed) Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

No idea what Im doing wrong. App works fine locally, but I keep getting an application error page and a [H10 error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed).  Ill post the rails console output because I read that would be more useful then just the heroku logs, but I can put that here to if needed. I really hope this is not going to be ignored as I am at a total lose right now.

Rails console:

```
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.8093
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_
matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `request'
 for Session (call 'Session.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NameEr
ror)
        from /app/app/models/session.rb:3:in `<class:Session>'
        from /app/app/models/session.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.
rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.
rb:471:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.
rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.
rb:469:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.
rb:469:in `eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.
rb:346:in `eager_load!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/applica
tion/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/applica
tion/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tso
rt_each'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 lev
els) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongl
y_connected_component_from'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in eac
h_strongly_connected_component'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongl
y_connected_component'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initial
izable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/applica
tion.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_s
upport/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/applica
tion.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/command
s.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

heroku logs:

```
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932369+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_depe
ndency'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932388+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932407+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932426+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932465+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932485+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932504+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932523+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932610+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2015-07-05T20:21:38.932579+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932629+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932648+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932735+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932675+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932755+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932839+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in serv
er'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932859+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932878+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'

2015-07-05T20:21:38.932897+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932931+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-07-05T20:21:38.932951+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-07-05T20:21:39.917826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2015-07-05T20:21:39.919080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2015-07-05T20:21:39.901026+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-05T20:21:44.803632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 4674 -e production`
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648458+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648478+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.1 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:4674
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648480+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648481+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648482+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648756+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/
activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing':
 undefined local variable or method `request' for Session (call 'Session.connect
ion' to establish a connection):Class (NameError)
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648758+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/session.rb:
3:in `<class:Session>'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648762+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648763+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in
require'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648760+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/session.rb:
1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648766+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648764+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_depe
ndency'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648771+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_loa
d!'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648767+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_o
r_load'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648768+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on
'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648770+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_d
ependency'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648773+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648775+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648776+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648779+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648782+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module
:Finisher>'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648778+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648784+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648781+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648783+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648788+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/
ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_componen
t'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648786+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initialize
rs'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648787+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/
ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648789+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/
ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648793+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/
ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648790+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/
ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648795+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/
ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648792+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/
ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648796+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/
ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648798+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/
ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648803+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648805+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_depe
ndency'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648804+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in
require'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648806+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648815+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648800+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648813+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block
in <main>'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648801+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:
5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648817+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648820+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648825+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648821+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648826+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648829+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648832+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648816+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648839+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648819+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648823+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648824+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'

2015-07-05T20:21:50.648828+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648830+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648835+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'

2015-07-05T20:21:50.648831+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in serv
er'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648838+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648834+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648837+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1
.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-07-05T20:21:51.832370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-07-05T20:21:51.845270+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2015-07-05T20:23:44.683352+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake db:migrate` by dvid1994@gmail.com
2015-07-05T20:23:49.876519+00:00 heroku[run.7443]: Awaiting client
2015-07-05T20:23:49.931116+00:00 heroku[run.7443]: Starting process with command
 `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-07-05T20:23:55.352150+00:00 heroku[run.7443]: Process exited with status 0
2015-07-05T20:23:55.365935+00:00 heroku[run.7443]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2015-07-05T20:23:50.311272+00:00 heroku[run.7443]: State changed from starting t
o up
2015-07-05T20:25:16.824478+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by dvid1994@gmail.c
om
2015-07-05T20:27:09.578310+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=glacial-falls-7476.herokuapp.com request_id=6a99e
c01-98d6-45cf-bc2c-8ec05a0f7ab9 fwd="50.163.200.7" dyno= connect= service= statu
s=503 bytes=
2015-07-05T22:28:51.659970+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=glacial-falls-7476.herokuapp.com request_id=13681
1f6-73cf-4708-96a9-d48e26d61dd1 fwd="50.163.200.7" dyno= connect= service= statu
s=503 bytes=
```

production rake:

```
I, [2015-07-05T16:16:54.146798 #21460]  INFO -- : Writing C:/row/dev/project/public/assets/tapedek3-4343c22664d06b029040ca2311b3fc956f7fb61b1dc8aa0beb8b1e
bbe23c9e31.png
I, [2015-07-05T16:16:59.754119 #21460]  INFO -- : Writing C:/row/dev/project/public/assets/application-ddbb9538bbe5eff3b50ef226fc0aa9af7da7fa937082f4ef22b
7e8c339a0bcde.js
I, [2015-07-05T16:17:07.206545 #21460]  INFO -- : Writing C:/row/dev/project/public/assets/application-f0703cab74ba3b243988bfab9161553021c1568ea0daae042a2
b215f37284023.css
I, [2015-07-05T16:17:07.219546 #21460]  INFO -- : Writing C:/row/dev/project/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-13634da87d9e23f8c3ed9108
ce1724d183a39ad072e73e1b3d8cbf646d2d0407.eot
I, [2015-07-05T16:17:07.232546 #21460]  INFO -- : Writing C:/row/dev/project/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-42f60659d265c1a3c30f9fa4
2abcbb56bd4a53af4d83d316d6dd7a36903c43e5.svg
I, [2015-07-05T16:17:07.240547 #21460]  INFO -- : Writing C:/row/dev/project/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-e395044093757d82afcb1389
57d06a1ea9361bdcf0b442d06a18a8051af57456.ttf
I, [2015-07-05T16:17:07.245547 #21460]  INFO -- : Writing C:/row/dev/project/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-a26394f7ede100ca118eff2e
da08596275a9839b959c226e15439557a5a80742.woff
I, [2015-07-05T16:17:07.250547 #21460]  INFO -- : Writing C:/row/dev/project/public/assets/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-fe185d11a49676890d47bb78
3312a0cda5a44c4039214094e7957b4c040ef11c.woff2
```

Comment: Posting your Heroku log would be useful: $heroku logs

Comment: Added the heroku log. thanks

Answer (score 1):

### Rails assets pipeline

This may take a few iterations to step through. The first error that Heroku flags is a failed GET on /favicon.ico

```
2015-07-05T17:56:19.804219+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=glacial-falls-7476.herokuapp.com reque
st_id=091b3b97-bbab-4d13-b6a1-da24aa2b018b fwd="50.163.200.7" dyno= connect= ser
vice= status=503 bytes=
```

What this tell us is that there is an asset pipeline problem, because the app should be looking for something like the filename below, not the original filename:

> href="/assets/favicon-17897c732521afcc30d49410042fc687.ico"

The favicon filename should be the compiled asset name. There are a number of steps to debug this:

1. Did you execute a production rake prior to deployment?

```
$bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

2. Excellent, next step is to push the app to Heroku to deploy the app blob with assets properly compiled for the Rails asset pipeline.

```
$heroku push
```

If your app crashes, please post the updated Heroku log. If it runs, woohoo. That was the only problem.

3. So the easy solution didn't work. And it didn't even compile the .ico assets. That means there's some problem in the config, so it's not building the app blob correctly.

Aside from that there are a number of serious errors in the new log.

WEBrick should not be the server running on Heroku--that's a red flag. Do you know why WEBrick is launching?

The IP also Looks incorrect.

```
Rails 4.2.1 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:4674
```

Everything in this block needs to be fixed and I don't think it's going to be easy. Pushing a working app from development to Heroku is typically easy, I don't know what setting you have where that is throwing it into the weeds.  I'd look at the Gemfile, production,rb, application.rb  for all the differences there are for "development" versus "production"

```
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648458+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648478+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.1 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:4674
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648480+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more s
tartup options
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648481+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648482+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648756+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/
activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing':
 undefined local variable or method `request' for Session (call 'Session.connect
ion' to establish a connection):Class (NameError)
2015-07-05T20:21:50.648758+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/session.rb:
3:in `<class:Session>'
```

I wish I had a one-line answer, but I don't. I think there are several deploy issues that will need to be worked, one at a time.

My advice is that you scale down your app, or start with a dummy test app and deploy in stages.

Or maybe someone will come along with the complete answer...

Comment: ok I think I resolved the production rake issue and I added the output from it to my post.

Comment: ok well im still getting that error. Also there is no favicon.ico in my logs it has `path="/" ` not `path="/favicon.ico"` I checked my public folder and there is a favicon.ico there. Are you sure that is the problem? I updated my logs, but Im pretty sure its all the same.

Comment: I expected you'd have other problems. That's why I mentioned iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have require 'pry' anywhere in your file? If so remove it and redeploy, leaving this on causes an H10 issue with heroku.